# How to acces a nested json value when it has no key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can you access a nested json value when the value has no key?

im trying to access the "2019-03-19T22:57:47.972Z" value of this json object:

```
var json = {"metaData":[{"name":"ACTION_NAME"},{"name":"SENT_RECV_TIME"}],"rows":[["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T06:20:45.704Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-21T06:04:08.313Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-21T06:01:14.412Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T06:59:54.875Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T20:32:50.975Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:57:47.972Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:56:52.115Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:54:28.196Z"] ......
```

what is can reach rigth now is just json.rows[0], which return:

```
["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-21T06:04:08.313Z"]
```

I tried json.rows[0].[1] but this does not work.

I just need the second value "2019-03-21T06:04:08.313Z", how can I acces it?

Comment: `json.rows[0][1]` will give you results. as you can see `rows` is an array with depth `level 2` so you need to access using indexs

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2):

You can access nested values using json.rows[0][1], like this:

```js
var json = {"metaData":[{"name":"ACTION_NAME"},{"name":"SENT_RECV_TIME"}],"rows":[["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T06:20:45.704Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-21T06:04:08.313Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-21T06:01:14.412Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T06:59:54.875Z"],["SI_OA_CTPParameters","2019-03-20T20:32:50.975Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:57:47.972Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:56:52.115Z"],["SI_OA_CloudDataAddress","2019-03-19T22:54:28.196Z"]]};

console.log(json.rows[0][1]);
```

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware I can access a json value like this, I was thinking more of :
json.rows[0].1 or something like that.

Comment: No problem, feel free to select an answer using the checkmark so that this question can be seen as solved

Answer (score 1):

`json.rows[0]` returns an array. Lets call this array a.
You can reference the elements of an array by their index, thus: `a[1]` will yield your requested element.

However, renaming the array is not convenient, you can simply substitute the original statement back into the a; thus `json.rows[0][1]` will work.

Comment: thanks, you were right, I wasn't aware I can access json values this way.

Comment: No problem, good luck with the rest of your program!